# Document Sequential Numbered Printing

Tags: google-apps-script, ms-word, google-docs

I have a Google/Word document with a number in the right hand corner of the page starting at 001.

I need to print 100 copies of this document, but on each print the number needs to increment by one i.e. 001,002,003,004

Is there a way to do this is Microsoft Word or in Google Docs?

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot imagine `I have a Google/Word document with a number in the with hand corner starting at 001.`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: "I have a Google/Word document with a number in the with hand corner starting at 001" - could you clarify more on this statement? What do you mean by "with hand corner" ?

Comment: This isn't a programming question as it stands.

Comment: Apologies I meant "Right Hand Corner". Its a number in the top right of the page that needs to increment on one on each print.  @jonsson I asked it as a programming question because I thought maybe there was a way to do this with the VBA language in word or similar in google docs.

Comment: It's a little cumbersome but how about this... do an app script merge; create a merge code in the Doc, merge from a spreadsheet, increment the merge code/"print number" in the spreadsheet so that the merge code prints the unique value.